# oracle 11g column format not working

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

Im using oracle 11g ex edition. From a text book I found the format option but its not working.The table structure is as follows.

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------

ID                                                 NUMBER(4)
NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)
ADDRESS                                            VARCHAR2(20)
PINCODE                                             NUMBER(6)
LOCATION                                           NUMBER(2)
DOB                                                DATE
```

I used this command

```
 column name format A12
 select name "USERNAME" from hai;
```

I expected to display the column heading as **USERNAME**. But it displays only **USERN** . When using the format option it need to display 12 charcter but it showing only 5 as in the table definition. Why? The query result is given below

```
 USERN
 -----
 korna
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you didnot set format for USERNAME;

TRY THIS:

```
col USERNAME format a8
```